# How to create a virtual column to index JSON column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, join, indexing, mysql-workbench

I am using `MySql 8.0 verion` and my table looks as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tableType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jkey` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jval` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Here `jval` will always have 2 fields as below:

```
{"group": "group1@abc.com", "user": "user1"}

{"group": "group2@abc.com", "user": "user2"}
```

I am trying to add index to the `JSON column` `jval` but getting below error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 3152: JSON column 'jval' supports indexing only via generated columns on a specified JSON path.
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `db1`.`table1` 
ADD INDEX `jval` (`value` ASC) VISIBLE
```

How can I create a `virtual column` to index `jval` in MySQL?

Comment: Could you please share your mysql version ? mariadb ?

Comment: MySql 8.0 verion

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a way to index JSON documents directly, but it has given us an alternative: generated columns. we can index a JSON field.  Can you share the sample json and the field to be indexed

Comment: Here `jval` will have 2 values as below:

    {group1@abc.com, sme1}
    
    {group2@abc.com, sme2}

Comment: Its not a valid json. Just share a proper json and the `field` to be indexed

Comment: Here is the valid one, ["group1@abc.com", "user1" ]

["group2@abc.com", "user2" ]

Comment: Please understand one thing if your json is going to be as simple as ["group1@abc.com", "user1" ] then why do you want it as JSON column ? We need a key to index the values

Comment: thanks a lot for providing right guidance. the updated json now looks as below:  
`{"group": "group1@abc.com", "user": "user1"}

{"group": "group2@abc.com", "user": "user2"}`

Comment: And the field to be indexed is...`group` or `user`

Comment: I need index on `group` and `user` both

Comment: I don't see a column named `value` -- so the index will fail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a way to index JSON documents directly, but it has given us an alternative: generated columns. **By generating columns from values within a JSON document and then indexing that column, we can practically index a JSON field.**

**Syntax for `Generated Columns` is**

> `column_name` datatype GENERATED ALWAYS AS (expression)

You query will become like

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tableType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jkey` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jval` json NOT NULL,

  `group_virtual` VARCHAR(250) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`jval` ->> '$.group') NOT NULL, 
  `user_virtual` VARCHAR(250) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (`jval` ->> '$.user') NOT NULL,   
  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

You can check the virtual columns

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table1`;
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | 696e74 | NO | PRI |  |  |
| tableType | 7661726368617228343529 | YES |  |  |  |
| jkey | 7661726368617228343529 | YES |  |  |  |
| jval | 6a736f6e | NO |  |  |  |
| group_virtual | 766172636861722832353029 | NO |  |  | VIRTUAL GENERATED |
| user_virtual | 766172636861722832353029 | NO |  |  | VIRTUAL GENERATED |

if table is already created and you want to create Generated Columns, then use the following syntax

```
ALTER TABLE
    `table1` ADD COLUMN `user_virtual` VARCHAR(250) 
     GENERATED ALWAYS AS(`jval` - >> '$.user') NOT NULL 
AFTER `jval`;
```

**Dont forget to index the Generated Columns**

```
CREATE INDEX `users_idx` ON `table1`(`user_virtual`);
```

Then try

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table1;
```

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table1 | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 0 | *null* | *null* |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |
| table1 | 1 | users_idx | 1 | user_virtual | A | 0 | *null* | *null* |  | BTREE |  |  | YES |  |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16221bf48a885a63a31a81b0292c348a)*

Comment: Thanks Indra for your answer. I have already created the table. So, can you please suggest what will be the `Alter statement` in this scenario?

Comment: Actually, having both `Create` and `Alter` statements would be beneficial for reference in future.

Comment: @meallhour Please check the updated answer. You need to do 2 things 1) generate a virtual column 2) And index the generated one

Comment: Hey Indra! Does this mean that the index basically "caches" the results of the VIRTUAL expression, and when I query the index, it won't run the expression for all rows every time? And when is the index updated? Is it only when we run an UPDATE on that row? Many thanks!

Comment: Actually, my answer is here: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/ "The index itself is now material and it does exist (as all other indexes do)." (referring to an index on a VIRTUAL column)